# How to capitalize first letter with JSTL/CSS?

Tags: css, jsp, jstl

I am coding a JSP/JSTL application. I would like to style a link with the first letter uppercase and the rest lowercase. For example "my LINK" would become "My Link".

I saw that in CSS I can do:

```
<a href="..." style="text-transform: capitalize">${linkName}</a>
```

Which works only when ${linkName} is all lower case, but doesn't work as I want when is uppercase for instance if it contains "MY LINK" will be still displayed all uppercase.

I was wondering what is the best way to solve this problem, for instance it could be to use JSTL to convert ${linkName} to lower case.

Anyone knows how to do that? Or any alternative way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Great css solution to transform only the first letter if I can decide about my string and put it lowercase.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) functions [`fn:toLowerCase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/toLowerCase.fn.html) to lowercase a string.

So, this should do

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<a href="..." style="text-transform: capitalize">${fn:toLowerCase(linkName)}</a>
```

Comment: Interesting, I tried already and it works. Where can I learn more about this functions? Here http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html ?

Comment: Also see the TLD http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html It's also linked in our JSTL wiki page (click the JSTL link in my answer).

Comment: I was hoping for a pure CSS way, but sadly, I don't think there is one. +1.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I experimented with it too, but I couldn't make it work, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 21):

If you do not want to use CSS and only use JSTL, this solution have a bit extreme:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>


<a href="..." >
${fn:toUpperCase(fn:substring(linkName, 0, 1))}${fn:toLowerCase(fn:substring(linkName, 1,fn:length(linkName)))}
</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Apache Commons offers libraries to do lots of common useful tasks. WordUtils can help you here.

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("aaa BBB cCc");
```

Would output...

> Aaa Bbb Ccc

Reference for WordUtils: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully%28java.lang.String%29

On my web app I added a wrapper for this in my TLD file...

```
<function>
    <name>capitalize</name>
    <function-class>org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.String capitalizeFully(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
</function>
```

So now I can do this...

```
<p>Hello ${blah:capitalize(firstName)}</p>
```

I will leave you to read up on custom TLD files though, since other people explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

PFB the below code which would convert "i AM god" to "I Am God"

```
    <c:forEach var="word" items="${fn:split(fn:toLowerCase(stringToBeConverted),' ')}">
        <c:set var="formattedText" value="${formattedText} ${fn:toUpperCase(fn:substring(word,0,1))}${fn:toLowerCase(fn:substring(word,1,fn:length(word)))}" />
    </c:forEach>
```